# How to add options to command in menu, Eclipse Plugin

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to add options to my menu's commands. For example like how if you click "run as" it'll show more options as shown here:

[image]

What i am able to produce right now is just a menu and options for the menu.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
        <menu
            id="myExample.menus.sampleMenu"
            label="TOP MENU"
            mnemonic="M">     
            <command
                commandId="myCommand.commands.sampleCommand"
                id="myExample.menus.sampleCommand"
                mnemonic="S">
            </command>
        </menu> 
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'options'?

Comment: i am not sure if options is the correct term but what I want is to have it be like the "run as" command. First you click "Run" then that shows all the run submenus, then click "run as" and that shows even more options as shown in the picture. So i guess what I am asking is how to have another submenu in a submenu as shown in the "run as" picture.

Comment: In the `menuContribution` the `menu` can contain nested `menu` items as well as `command` items.

Comment: Ah thanks I tried that initially but I guess I did it wrong the first time, it works now by adding another menu. If you put this as the answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `menu` entry in the `menuContribution` can contain nested `menu` items as well as `command` and `dynamic` entries.

You can use the nested `menu` if you have a fixed number of items to add or `dynamic` if you want to generate entries dynamically in code.